# How to set a variable's value to uploaded file json data in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm new to angularJS. I want to upload a JSON file using 
    `<input      type="file"onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this.files)"/>`

and I am trying to access its data in the controller like this:

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(files) {

$scope.jsonData = files[0].data;

};
```

But I get an undefined in my variable. I have to use this variable to populate various other fields on the website. Kindly help me how to access the data of the input file uploaded.

Comment: Just `files[0]`

Comment: @Satpal but how do I get the data in the file turned into an object ?

Answer (score 1):

You need use [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) API.

> The FileReader object lets web applications asynchronously read the contents of files (or raw data buffers) stored on the user's computer.

Its method [FileReader.readAsText()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText)

> The `readAsText` method is used to read the contents of the specified Blob or File.

Note: Here is an example, It works in Modern browsers

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#file').change(function(e) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      console.log(e.target.result);
      
      //if you want in JSON use      
      //var json = JSON.parse(e.target.result)
    }
    reader.readAsText(this.files[0]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
```

Comment: But this is returning me the raw data of the file, not the way I want to use it . It is not in the form of an object for which I can access it's "values" based on "keys"

Answer (score 0):

Just Another way to go around... if you don't want to use the `FileReader` and manually parse the text using `JSON.parse` and also wrapping it around a try/catch in case of wrong format

```js
// simulate a file `file = files[0]`
var file = new Blob(['{"hello": "world"}'])

new Response(file).json().then(
  json => console.log(json),
  err => console.error("invalid json data")
)
```

Or with the help of [Screw-FileReader](https://github.com/jimmywarting/Screw-FileReader)

```js
// simulate a file `file = files[0]`
var file = new Blob(['{"hello": "world"}'])

file.json().then(json => console.log(json))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jimmywarting/Screw-FileReader/master/index.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the OP)*.

Thank you @Satpal I solved it using fileReader.readAsText() and JSON.parse().