# Get a file's contents when opening via input file tag in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using input tag as file in HTML and trying to open a text file. For that first I need to get the contents of the file. It was quite easy in C# as it can be done using StreamReader but I cannot find a way to read file in JQuery or javascript. I have tried the following code :

```
<body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#fileDialog").on('change', function (args) {
                debugger;
                var file = this.files[0];
            });
        });
    </script>
    <input id="fileDialog" accept=".abc" style="display: none; margin: 0 auto;" type="file" />
</body>
```

This abc is the extension of my file that is basically a type of text file only but just with some xml formatting i.e. it is in readable form.

this.files[0] returns the following :
[image]

I don't get the actual file path, so cannot figure out any way to read the file.
Can anyone help me to read the file contents via this file dialog in HTML as it can be done using Streamreader in c#.

Comment: You can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL

Comment: @Satpal, your dupe is not a correct one, here the readAsDataURL method won't help OP, he wants readAsText and there are probably dupes I can't find right now.

Comment: @Kaiido, then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262063/how-to-set-a-variables-value-to-uploaded-file-json-data-in-angularjs

Comment: Thanks!! readAsText function worked for me..